# Can I take my slime downstairs?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I have an ability called "Slime-Herder" that allows me to conjure an ally slime. Is it possible to make this slime follow me when I go downstairs?
I've been trying with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't believe so.  It's not spelled out anywhere in the documentation or on the Dredmor wiki, but I've died and rerolled many a character, some who could summon different types of pets, (along with various wands that have pet effects) and none of my pets has ever traveled down stairs with me.